# perl script can't read file in other directories

Tags: perl

I am writing a script that only reads files. An issue I've run into is that if I pass in a path (using Getoptions::Long), it tells me the file or directory does not exist even though it can print me the file name. For example:

> thomaswtsang@alfred:perl$ perl ~/Dropbox/dev/test-monkey/perl/fileReader.pl --path ~/Dropbox/dev/test-monkey/diff
>
> No such file or directory:f1.txt at /Users/thomaswtsang/Dropbox/dev/test-monkey/perl/fileReader.pl line 67.

And then...cd-ing to that directory...

> thomaswtsang@alfred:diff$ perl ~/Dropbox/dev/test-monkey/perl/fileReader.pl --path ~/Dropbox/dev/test-monkey/diff
>
> (1/3)Reading f1.txt...
>
> (2/3)Reading f2.txt...
>
> Read 21 Bs
>
> Complete!

I don't really understand why I'm getting such behavior. Permissions issue?

```
my $path = shift;
my $run_in_fg = shift;
if (length($path) == 0){
    if ($run_in_fg){print "Using current directory...\n";}
    $path = cwd();
}
print $path . "\n";
opendir my $dir, $path or die "Cannot open directory: $!";
my @files = readdir $dir;
my $num_files = $#files;
my $i = 1;
my $total_size = 0;
$SIG{'INT'} = sub {print "\n";print_read_size($total_size); exit 1;};

foreach my $file (@files){
    if ($file =~ m/^\.+$/){next;}
    $file =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;
    open FILE, "<", $file or die "$!:$file";
    if ($run_in_fg){ print "($i/$num_files)Reading $file...\n";}
    while (my $line = <FILE>){
        #don't need to actually print to screen, just load to memory
    }
    $total_size += -s $file;
    close FILE or die $!;
    $i++;
}

print_read_size($total_size);
print "Complete!\n";
```

If there are better approaches, please kindly point out, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 open FILE, "<", $file or die "$!:$file";
```

This line tries to open `$file` —  in the current directory. Specifically, `readdir` returns file names, not paths. Therefore, it is neccessary to prepend the correct path:

```
  my $filepath = "$path/$file";
  open FILE, "<", $filepath or die "$!:$filepath";
```

---

#### Comments on style:

```
my $i = 1;
for my $file (@files){
  ...;
  $i++;
}
```

is better expressed as

```
for my $i (1 .. @files) {
   my $file = $files[$i - 1];
   ...;
}
```

And `if`-conditions without an `else` that only contain one expression can be changed from

```
if (COND) {EXPR}
```

to

```
EXPR if COND;
```

which I find easier to read.

Next, `readdir` does not append a newline to the filenames. Therefore, it is unneccessary and *wrong* to remove newlines from the end of the filename—these may be legal characters of filenames in some filesystems<sup>(1)</sup>. So

```
$file =~ s/[\r\n]+$//;
```

is an unneccessary bug.

<sub>1: Examples include the Ext2–Ext4 family (all characters except `/` and `\0`), HFS (all chars except `:`), NTFS in Posix mode (all except `/` and `\0`), and NTFS in Win32 mode additionally disallows `\`, `*`, `?`, `:`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`.</sub>

In perl5, v10 and later,

```
print SOMETHING, "\n";
```

can be expressed as

```
use feature 'say'; # or use VERSION where VERSION >= 5.10

say SOMETHING;
```

When opening a file, it is best to use lexical variables as a file handle:

```
open my $fh, "<", $filepath or die "$!:$filepath";
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
  ...;
}
```

Lexical filehandles are closed automatically when their reference count drops to zero. However, explicit closing may be preferable for better diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks, totally overlooked that. Also, thanks for style comments! @amon

Answer (score 1):

You need prefix the `$path` to filenames what are comes from `readdir`, e.g.

```
 my @files = grep { ! -d $_ } map { "$path/$_" } readdir $dir;
```

The above prefixes all directory entries with the `$path` and removes all directories from the result (because you don't want open them).